Checking 'No-resonance' condition for the eigenvalues of a discrete Laplacian matrix with Dirichlet boundary condition
1-D discrete Laplacian matrix (finite difference scheme) has eigenvalues as (page-2 in ref.):
$$\lambda_j = sin^2(\frac{j\pi}{2(N+1)});\ j\in \{1, 2, ..., N\}$$ Where $N$ is the number of discretization points in the spatial domain.

No-resonance for a matrix is defined in terms of its eigenvalue as (last para page-3 in ref.):
$$\lambda_j \neq \sum_{j=1}^N m_j\lambda_j;\ \forall m_j\in \mathbb{Z}\ \ and\ m_j\geq 0$$
$$such\ that\ \sum_{j=1}^{n}m_j\geq 2$$
Or, no-resonance condition occurs if any eigenvalues can't be expressed as (positive) integer linear combination of the other eigenvalues. Where, the trivial case of $\lambda_j = \lambda_j +0 + 0+...$ is excluded.
My query is :

Is the no-resonance condition valid to the eigenvalues of the above 1-D discrete Laplacian matrix?


My attempt: First, I hypothesized that the no-resonance condition doesn't hold for the matrix.
I started checking the condition by considering a simple case (hoping to find a counter-example).
I took N =8 and tried testing its eigenvalues in Matlab.
Case-I: I tried testing if any eigenvalue can be written as a linear combination of any two. Or,
$$sin^2(\frac{j\pi}{2(N+1)}) = sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{2(N+1)}) + sin^2(\frac{l\pi}{2(N+1)})$$
Then, Case II: If any eigenvalue is a linear combination of any three. Or,
$$sin^2(\frac{j\pi}{2(N+1)}) = sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{2(N+1)}) + sin^2(\frac{l\pi}{2(N+1)}) + sin^2(\frac{m\pi}{2(N+1)})$$
where, $j,\ k,\ l,\ m\ ... \in \{1, 2, ..., N\}$ and these indices are allowed to take same value.
I cannot find a counter-example to my hypothesis that the no-resonance condition doesn't hold for the matrix.

Now, I have started reasoning from the other way.

Do these trigonometric conditions (case-I and II) have no solution for any $j,\ k,\ l,\ m ...$?

I am unaware of any trigonometric result that can help me prove or disprove it.

I would like to know if a certain trigonometric result can help me resolve the hypothesis.


If $3 | N + 1$, there's the easy case that $\sin^2(2\pi / 3) = 3\sin^2(\pi/3)$.

@eyeballfrog, you mean $sin^2(2\pi /3)= 4 sin^2 (\pi /3)$. Thanks!

@eyeballfrog, the original post had a typo. My bad! Instead of $sin^2(j\pi/(N+1))$, it should be $sin^2(j\pi/2(N+1))$. Now, I am searching to see if a new counter-example exists. // Thanks for your time, eyeballfrog. And sorry for disturbing you again.
